# Remove Sign in and Create account links from header Magento 2

Tags: magento2, toplinks

I used following code for remove top links **Create Account** link successfully removed but **Sign in** link still show so can u please check and let me know what is the correction.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />      <!--for Sign In Link  -->
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use below code for remove sign in link

```
 <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Bingo... Its Working for me

Comment: can you accept answer @PratikPatel ?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the 'authorization-link-login' block in default.xml file of your theme.

```
 <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true"/>
```

Remember to flush cache after that.

Comment: it is better if we write in referenceContainer header.container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide and show header with respect to customer login/logout

add this in body of file
`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="vendor\module\Block\Headerlinks" name="history-link" after="my-account-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>    
        </referenceBlock>
```

and in file `Headerlinks` add

```
    <?php
namespace vendor\module\Block;


class Headerlinks extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = [],
         \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Render block HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        if ($customer->isLoggedIn()) {
             $link = '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('customer/account/') . '" title="Account & Security">Account & Security</a></li>';
             $link .= '<li><a href="' . $this->getUrl('sales/order/history/') . '" title="Purchase History">Purchase History</a></li>';
        return $link;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```